# How to Stringify a Cyclic Object in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to stringify a cyclic object in my typescript. Here is my original code & error:

**app.component.ts:**

```
updateList(list: any) {
    this.demolist = Array.apply(this, list);
    console.log('List - ' + JSON.stringify(this.demolist));
}
```

> TypeError: cyclic object value

I then tried the following code inside my *updateList()* method:

```
const getCircularReplacer = () => {
      const seen = new WeakSet();
      return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
          if (seen.has(value)) {
            return;
          }
          seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
      };
    };
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.demolist, getCircularReplacer()));
}
```

But now I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: toISOString property is not callable

Can someone please show me what changes I need to make to display the contents of my ***this.listBase***?

Here is my HTML:

```
<upload #fileUpload (listChange)="updateList($event)" data-kind="primary" restrictFiles=".pdf,.doc,.docx">
</upload>

<list #listBase [IncludeComponent]="inputComponent" [list]="demolist">    
</list>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code where this error occurs... please review what constitutes a [mcve] for more information.  My guess right now is that you are doing something weird with a `Date` object.

Comment: @jcalz  `JSON.stringify(this.listBase)` is where the first error is occurring because it's trying to serialise a cyclic object. `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.listBase, getCircularReplacer()));` is where the new error occurs

Comment: I'm not sure the error you are getting is *directly* related to your replacer function, but may have something to do with what is in your list. Could you perhaps post an example of what this.demoList looks like?

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are getting:

> TypeError: toISOString property is not callable

Means that somewhere a **property** named `toISOString` of some object has been called as if it was a method. e.g.:

```
someObj.toISOString();
```

The only method known in Javascript to be built-in and named `toISOString` is the `Date.prototype.toISOString`.

JSON.stringify() knows about some standard value types and how to convert (serialize) them to a string. It usually accomplishes that by calling the expected-to-exist `toString()` method on them. It also knows that the `Date` object has a `toISOString()` method and calls that instead whenever it finds one. Therefore in this case I assume that `JSON.stringify()` encounters an object inside the `this.demoList` that although is of type `Date`, yet it has a defined **property** named `toISOString` (instead of a method), which overrides the existing `Date.prototype.toISOString()`, and at that point it tries to call it as a method and you get this error.

I am unable to guess which is this object in your particular case, so I suggest that you should examine all the objects that are inside the `this.demoList` one by one (and their children) using the developer tools of your browser and find out which one is the "offending" object.